# What is this fruit?

Tags: fruit, food-identification

It was bought in southern China. At first I mistook it for a ripening date..same size, color and similar shape. However it has a fuzzy and thicker skin. The skin has a very green flavor, the flesh is citrus flavored. There's no pit. And the skin is attached to the meat, but can be peeled.

It's like a mix between a date (size/color), a kiwi (skin) a lemon (flavor somewhat) and a longan (flash texture).

[image: Here's a picture]

Answer (score 5):

My best guess would be [wampee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wampee) fruit - has roughly the same size, shape, and stem colour, and obviously comes from the same region, although I'm not sure about the interior:

[image: Wampee]

It's hard to tell from the low contrast in the photo but it could also be [loquat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loquat), AKA "Japanese Plum".

[image: Loquat]

Only problem with the second choice is that loquat usually has full-on brown branches as opposed to green stems - so it's probably the wampee.

Comment: Probably not a loquat, as those are bigger, and have several large pits.

Answer (score 2):

They remind me of the canepas ([Melicoccus bijugatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamoncillo)) common in the Caribbean and tropical regions of central and South America.  Beyond that I'd only be guessing that they are likely a member of the Sapindaceae family of Soapberries.

Comment: If there's no pit it's definitely not a canepa!